# Horizontally sliding gallery with visible neighbors?

Tags: views, media, javascript

I'm looking for a way to create a horizontally sliding gallery, where the non-"highlighted" images can be seen to the left and right of the "highlighted" image, instead of a normal slideshow where there is just a transition to the next image in a static box.

Essentially, the functionality shown by [Royal Slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/), and also demonstrated on the [WeArInteractive](http://www.wearinteractive.com/) homepage under "Featured Works."

The only thing that I can find that's close is [ImageFlow](https://drupal.org/project/imageflow), but it's not quite the same and has some other odd functionality that I don't prefer.

The popular gallery/slider modules that I have found don't seem to have a built in way to do this, but maybe somebody has figure out a way to do it? I don't mind using views as part of the solution, as I'm assuming that will probably be a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That technique is most often referred to as a carousel.

I would recommend [Owl Carousel module](https://drupal.org/project/owl-carousel) (or as a stand alone library depending on how custom you need it) as it is highly configurable and has support for mobile devices as well.

You can check out their (non-Drupal) [demo here](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/).

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I have looked into carousels before (actually maybe just jCarousel), but haven't seen that exactly built in (or at least demo'd). I'll have to make sure, but Owl Carousel does seem to do what I need.